# Ada Hash_type to integer

Tags: hash, type-conversion, ada

im trying to implement my own hash function as a wrapper to Strings.hash
with an upper bound, here is my code:

```
function hash (k : in tcodigo; b : in positive) return natural is
      hash: Ada.Containers.Hash_Type;
   begin
      hash := Ada.Strings.Hash(String(k));
      return  integer(hash) mod b;
   end hash;
```

My problem is that i dont know how to cast hash to integer so i can make the mod operation.

Comment: We have no idea what a `tcodigo` is. Some sort of String, obviously. In this case, I suspect it doesn’t matter; normally we’d ask you to show us the compiler error message, but in this case there isn’t one, because the code is legal. Unless you can show us different, of course. I recommend compiling with `-gnatl` (after creating a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Reference Manual (A.18.1) `Hash_Type` is a modular type.  Therefore, a simple `Integer(Hash)` should work.  Actually, I guess you can take directly the `mod` of the hash by first casting b to `Hast_Type` and then converting the result to `Natural`. Remember to add `use type Ada.Containers.Hash_Type`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the hashing function from the notes; if you don't have it at hand, I'll leave it here:

```
function hash(k: in string) return natural is
   s, p: natural;
begin
   s:= 0;
   for i in k'range loop
      p:= character'pos(k(i)); -- código ASCII
      s:= (s+p) mod b;
   end loop;
   return s;
end hash;
```

See you on Monday at the exam; good luck and study hard!